Sum over an index that needs to fulfill a condition
Introduction

I have a matrix $V=(v_{ij})_{1\leq i \leq m, 1\leq j \leq n}$ containing integer numbers, representing the number of vehicles.
Each $i-$row represents the place of origin of those vehicles, which all go to the same place of destination.
Each $j-$column represents the type of vehicle.
For each row, I know the distance from the place of origin to the place of destination, contained in the column vector $D = (d_i)$.
As an example, the first row of the matrix $v_{1j} = \{3,2,1,1,3\}$ and the first element of the column vector $d_1=5$ indicate that (i), $10$ vehicles come from a certain place of origin, which is far $5$ km from the common place of destination, and (ii), among these vehicles $3$ of them are cars, $2$ are buses, $1$ is a trucks, $1$ is a motorbike, and $3$ are bicycles.
I bin the distances covered by the vehicles from $1$ to $100$ km, by using $e=\{1,5,10,20,50,100\}$ (in km) as edges for $5$ bins. In this way, I can indicate a bin as $b_k = \{ d_i | d_i \in [e_{k},e_{k+1}) \}$, where $k = 1, \ldots, (|e|-1)$, and the symbol $|$ would indicate "such that". For example, the first bin would read as $b_1 = \{ d_i | d_i \in [1,5) \}$.

Question
To indicate the total number of vehicles $T_k$, of all types, and that travel in each range of distances, i.e. for each "bin of distances", I would use the following notation:
$T_k = \sum_{\{i \, | \, e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}\}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} v_{ij}, \quad  \
\text{where} \quad k = 1, \ldots, (|e|-1)$
Here, all the types of vehicles would be counted through the second sum, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}$.
But, would it be (allowed or) common in math, to select the $i-$rows of a math object, i.e. the matrix $V$, through a condition, $\sum_{\{i \, | \, e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}\}}$, which is based on other two math objects, i.e. the column vector $D$ and the set $e$ of bins edges?
In other words, would the condition over the $i-$index, i.e. $\sum_{\{i \, | \, e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}\}}$, make sense in math?

If I understand you correctly, you seem to want $T=\sum_k \sum_i \sum_j$.

Just the $T_k$, i.e. for each $k$... I corrected it.... sorry...

but my question would be about the condition $\sum_{{i , | , e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}}$, if it makes sense in math... since I do not remember such a thing in the past, in my background... but maybe it is common and legitimate in math...

Well, $\sum_{i \in S}$ (where some set $S$ is already understood) is quite common notation. So I don’t know that anyone would object to yours.

Thanks a lot! Just a tiny doubt... If I understood correctly, in this case it would be
$\sum_{i \in S} = \sum_{i \in {i , | , e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}}$.... But, would it be still correct that $i$ belongs to a set made of $i$, i.e. $i \in {i  , | ...}$ ?? (I mean, in $i \in {i , | , e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}$) ......Or, would it be better to write $S = {e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}$ and therefore $i \in {e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}$? Or both are OK?

I wouldn’t introduce notation about $S$, I used $S$ merely as a placeholder for a broad class of notation for sums. And you definitely don’t want tongues the same variable (here $i$) both as a dummy in your set-builder not stand as a member of the set.

Thanks, I understood your first sentence, but not the second one...
As far as I understood, I can use (1) $\sum_{{i , | , e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}}$, but I did not understand if I can use also (2) $\sum_{i \in {e_{k} \leq d_i < e_{k+1}}}$......

My concern is with constructions of the form $i \in {i | P(i)}$ (here $P(i)$ stands for any predicate involving $i$). One way to avoid the problem is to use something like $i’ \in {i | P(i)}$.

Ahhhhh, got it!! Thanks a lot! :-)

I’ve only just now noticed that what I intended above as “to use,” the autocorrect morphed into “tongues.”  Oops.

No worries, after re-reading a few times I undertood it... :-)

Oh, jeez! It also turned an intended “notation and” into “not stand”!

no worrries :-)
